# which is right way for maintain user detail session or modelandview in spring mvc?

Tags: spring

Hi good morning to everyone 
currently I am working in spring. I am searching long time to work with session but somebody told use Model And View instead of session which is right way for maintain user status and give some referral link for session tracking.

Comment: The `Model` (from `ModelAndView`) is used to pass data from controller to view. It normally consists of *request* attributes, but can also contains *session* ones. The *session* is used to maintain state for one connection between requests. I really cannot understand what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between (Model & view) and session, Both are two different things.
Model and view is used to pass data from controller to view(interaction between controller and view). we need to create different model and view objects for different operations (CRUD operations) in a web application.
In case of session if we wanted to store any object, object type,variables  and want to use those for entire application for that particular session. Then we can go for session. This can be done by using annotation of @Scope("session") or we can configure in spring configuration file.

If you want to maintain user details for a particular session you can use session. If your requirement is to show the user details from database in view then you can use Model and view in controller.